# How to simplify multiple for statements in Python with relational lists

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to simplify the below Python, because I believe that it's likely very inefficient and I'm doing it the wrong way. Using SQL I would just use some joins, but I'm unsure how to simplify in Python. I'm using a database of politicians, which are dictionaries (legislative body) of areas/memberships/persons (lists) which then contain the individual records (dictionaries). For every single congressional district, I want to print the name of that district, then print the respective representative. These are linked through the memberships table. Is there a more efficient method to conduct this matching?

```
for state in housedata['areas']:
    print(state['name'])
    for position in housedata['memberships']:
        if position['legislative_period_id'] == currentlegislature and state['id'] == position['area_id']:
            for person in housedata['persons']:
                if person['id'] == position['person_id']:
                    print(person['given_name'], person['family_name'])
```

Comment: It looks like you need to redesign your data structures. Instead of searching lists by properties, you need to make those properties the keys of a dictionary.

Comment: You might 'flatten' teh code by using the principles of `functional programming`. Try to reduce all these operations into simple functions that do one operation only (don't forget to name these function with helpful names). In that way you'll be able to keep your logic separate from the execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the loops that search for matching elements with dictionary lookups. Before the loops, construct dictionaries keyed by the properties you want to match.

```
position_by_area = {}
for position in housedata['memberships']:
    if position['legislative_period_id'] == currentlegislature:
        position_by_area[position['area_id']] = position

person_by_id = {}
for person in housedata['persons']:
    person_by_id[person['id']] = person

for state in housedata['areas']:
    print(state['name'])
    position = position_by_area[state['id']]
    person = person_by_id[position['person_id']]
    print(person['given_name'], person['family_name'])
```

As you said, your loops are analogous to joins in a database. These dictionaries are analogous to the indexes you would create in your database to optimize the joins.